# phpdaemon (phpdaemon.net)

Tags: php, daemon

Im playing around with a script that should be used as an invocationscript for my service. It uses MongoDB for datastorage.

Right now im using Apache as webserver, but im not satisfied with the perfomance. I have been looking at phpdaemon from http://phpdaemon.net, and wants to try that out. But i cant figure out how to make a simple example run.

I have installed phpdaemon and are using the example config. I can run phpd and i tells that FastCGI is up. But from here im stuck.

If i try to call the server from browser on port 9000 nothing happens.

Could someone help me setup a simple example setup that will be working?

BR/Sune

Comment: This is more of a system configuration question than a programming question, and so belongs on serverfault.com